# Use Docker with my Ubuntu 14.04 (web access)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 by using repositories. I have version 1.6.2 build 7c8fca2.

I've launch my image with command :

`docker run -p 80:80 -v /workspace/private/workbench/:/current private/client`

This image launch a webserver I need to access... So I need the Docker's container's IP.

When I type :

`docker inspect 8f1526ff5287`

I have this response with empty IPAddress :

`"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": null
    },`

How can I know/define this IP ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When using port mapping you're mapping a port on your host to redirect traffic to the port on the container.
So in order to access your service running in a container that was executed with -p 80:80, You simply need to go to http://localhost:80/

Comment: While that's true, there's something else going on here: you would normally expect the `NetworkSettings` section of the `docker inspect` output to contain the container's ip address, even when using port mapping, unless you've started a container with `--net=host` (which doesn't appear to be the case here).

Comment: localhost:80 doesn't work...  but now I have this error when I run my image:
`FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container bf55256491e78265714a41c80b25176092ef2f571ddfe10b3d1f7a42dd9a5d87: [8] System error: mountpoint for devices not found`

Answer (score 0):

is port 80 exposed in the image file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the image's maintainer ;)

Yes, the ports are exposed... and this image work well on my MacBook (with Kitematick)...

The problem is I can't help him to launch my image on his Ubuntu since on my Apple, the container has an IP like 192.168.99.100... and I need to call it to have access to the webserver...